# protect web page from ajax request

Tags: php, ajax

i want to know the best way to protect my php scripts from ajax requests that did not originate from my site or by the use of Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Because it is possible for external pages to call my php codes with ajax requests. 
Thanks

Comment: I want to know what you've tried already (or why you think you're susceptible to this cross-origin request).

Comment: if your code receiving a specific variable then you can add if(isset($_POST['your_variable_name'])) in the beginning of your code and if it is not set then cancel the ajax

Comment: There's nothing you can do to prevent other pages from sending AJAX requests to your server. Someone can do it from the CLI using `curl`. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is used to tell the client not to use the response, it doesn't prevent the request.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP Headers are set on your HTTP Server, Apache for instance. So, if you don't set the *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* [header within Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_headers.html) (in apache.conf or .htaccess file) nor PHP (with [header() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)), **Cross domain requests are not allowed by default**.

Otherwise, if you need to, you can set in this header the only domains allowed to request your server.

Note that in @FluxCoder's answer the code is not 'safe', because HTTP_REFERER is set and sent by the Web Browser so it can be hacked by any user easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP to determine the HTTP-REFER, but this can cause an issue as it might not help you at all depending on who is targeting your site via Ajax Requests, you could use the bellow code where the Ajax Request is accepted.

Code:

```
$website = "http://domain.com/";

if(preg_match("%".$website."%", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
  //Allowed
} else {
  //Not Allowed
}
```

Other than that I don't really think there is many other options than using the HTTP_REFERER in PHP.

Comment: Referer can easily be forged.